# No matching provisioning profile specified entitlements

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, provisioning-profile

I know this question has been asked a lot but I don't get it to work.
I just wanted to upload my App to the app store like I did a lot of times before with other apps.
But when I go to the organizer and want to validate or upload it I only get the following error:

[image]

Now I tried everything I could find. All profiles are correct and up-to-date.

I don't know if this has anything to do with capabilities. I have the capability "Background modes" (specifically "Location updates" and "Uses Bluetooth LE accessories") activated in my app. But that's nothing I can activate under "App IDs" in "Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles"

And I don't know if it's just the entitlements and how to handle them.

Comment: might be your certificate may expired. kindly check in keychain that certificate are uptodate. or it has a private key or not. If that all are fine then delete all old provisional profile and generate new one for the app by selecte valide cer from ios dev center and download it and double click on it. hope that works.

Comment: if you are using any extension then you must be create individule bundle id for that and provisional profile. regulare app bundle id and provisional profile wont work for extension (today, keyboard. etc)

Comment: The certificate is uptodate. I deleted all old provisional profiles and generated new ones but that didn't help.
I also don't have any extensions in use (just mapkit.framework)

Comment: join at my skyep : nitin.gohel10

Comment: I could solve the issue by deleting the provisional profiles manually under ~/Library/MobileDevices/Provisioning Profile/ than creating a new provisional profile in the dev center, download and install it.

Comment: you've fixed this issue?